# Behaviour of case_when with numeric(0)

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I have a problem understanding how `dplyr::case_when` works. Here with this pretty simple line :

```
library(tidyverse)
case_when(TRUE ~ 50,
          FALSE ~ numeric(0))
```

I get `numeric(0)` while obviously, TRUE is TRUE and so it should send back 50. Besides, FALSE is FALSE so it should never send back numeric(0). I have not the problem if I write :

```
case_when(TRUE ~ 50,
      FALSE ~ NaN)
```

Where I get 50, which is right.
What do I miss ?

Comment: I think the problem is that numeric(0) returns a vector of length 0. If you try numeric(1) (which is a vector of length 1 with a value of 0) then it works. case_when should be reporting an error I would say, but it's not.

Comment: For me this is unwanted behavour and I wasn't aware of it. Maybe you can notice the `dplyr` team on github.
Generally, every outcome of `case_when` should have the same type and the same length. For example, `case_when(TRUE ~ 1:3, FALSE ~ 1:2)` throws an error.

Comment: Huh, on rereading the question, I was assuming (and mis-reading) that the first code block failed. It should, in my mind. I'm with @Cettt, this is unwanted behavior.

Comment: Apparently the [dplyr team sees this as a feature?](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4852)

Comment: It is complicated though. My immediate reaction is that I don't want `case_when` evaluating things it doesn't need to. I'd forego length checking for efficiency. `case_when(TRUE ~ 1, FALSE ~ {Sys.sleep(10); 0})` takes 10 seconds to return, but it could be instant.

Comment: `if_else` and `case_when` are not short-circuited, @GregorThomas; while I agree that it would be a great thing, I don't think it's in the cards to make it so. :-(

Comment: Apparently not. I had assumed that was one of the things `if_else` did to improve performance over `ifelse`, but `base::ifelse(TRUE, 1, {Sys.sleep(10); 0})` actually is short-circuited!

Comment: I am opening a new issue, because the documentation seems murky at the very least.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I disagree about optimizing out length-checking: R recycling, as long as its been around, has led to so many bugs when not recognized. When recycling is not desired but it *just happens to be* that the one vector length is a multiple of the other, recycling happens and likely corrupts the data. In my head, recycling should be length-same or length-1, nothing else unless explicitly allowed `</rant>`. Unlikely to change in base R, unfortunately. But `dplyr` makes intentional effort on things similar to this (enforcing `class`, e.g., when `ifelse` does not), surprised about this.

Comment: I agree with you 100% on recycling - I love data.table's approach there as well. But this seems more restrictive. Why does this throw warnings? `x <- 1:-1; case_when(x > 0 ~ log(x), TRUE ~ as.numeric(x))`.

Comment: `fcase` warns, too ... and it does no recycling (a problem in my book), so `TRUE` would need to be `rep(TRUE,3)` here (c.f., https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4258, still open).